# Why in the world does a button have to be defined after setContentView?

Tags: android, button, view, android-activity

So I just spent 4 hours trying to get my code to work and I realized it was something so dumb. I was defining a button before my setContentView(blablabla); was called. Why on earth did this cause my app to crash? 
         `Button schoolNameButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.schoolNameButton); setContentView(myVIew);`

Comment: because setContentView(blablabla) will initialize that button (amongst other things) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `setContentView` is actually the place where you are setting your UI for current Activity. Doing that the system knows which UI elements are associated with this Activity and it's where all the elements are need to initialized - after `setContentView()`. Of course if you are not doing something like this :

```
LinearLayout myLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
setContentView(myLayout);
```

Here is the explanation of `setContentView` from SDK :

> public void setContentView (int layoutResID)
>
> Added in API level 1 Set the activity content from a layout resource.
>   The resource will be inflated, adding all top-level views to the
>   activity.
>
> public void setContentView (View view)
>
> Set the activity content to an explicit view. This view is placed
>   directly into the activity's view hierarchy. It can itself be a
>   complex view hierarchy. When calling this method, the layout
>   parameters of the specified view are ignored. Both the width and the
>   height of the view are set by default to MATCH_PARENT. To use your own
>   layout parameters, invoke setContentView(android.view.View,
>   android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams) instead.

Answer (score 0):

its because the system needs to know in which activity/layoutview its going to perform its action.so first of all we need to specify the layout(setcontent View).then all the elements like Buttons,imageViews,TextViews etc will be identified there after.